# MapBox Android application crashes after update to SDK 4.1.0 when loading credentials

Tags: android, crash, mapbox

After the update to Android DropBox SDK 4.1.0 my application most of the time crashes with:

> MapboxEventManager: Error Trying to load Staging Credentials:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference

and no stack trace.

MapBox example on https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo crashes with the same error (both compiled locally and downloaded from Google Play).

Is this known problem? Is there any way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue, for now you can try [clearing the apps cache](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-clear-app-cache-and-app-data-in-android-6-0-marshmallow/). Switching the map style url to a different one will potentially fix the issue as well. A bug fix will be out later today for iOS and Android, you can follow the Android [release here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5725).

EDIT:
`4.1.1` has now been released, you can upgrade in your Grade file. More information can be [found here](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#gradle).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, beside that, I had :
OfflineManager: Failed to read the storage key: null

So both error message refer to same problem. The solution is clear apps cache. As cammace said, it solve my problem.