# Fatal signal 11 for Mapbox gl 4.2.1 for android 4.0.4

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am following the demo app for using Mapbox with Android Studio, but my app keeps crashing with the following error:

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)

My java and xml files math the code provided in the following demo: https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Below is the list of errors:

```
01-09 17:49:21.898: E/dalvikvm(3182): Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources 
01-09 17:49:21.898: E/dalvikvm(3182): Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache 
01-09 17:49:21.953: E/MapboxEventManager(3182): Error Trying to load Staging Credentials: java.lang.NullPointerException 
01-09 17:49:22.148: E/dalvikvm(3182): Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering    
01-09 17:49:22.210: E/OfflineManager(3182): Failed to read the storage key: null 
01-09 17:49:22.937: A/libc(3182): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)at 0x00000000 (code=1)
```

Below is my Build.grade:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pmbi002.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.2.1@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }

}
```

Below is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.TelemetryService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is my Java Code:

```
package xxx;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.MapboxAccountManager;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
        // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
        MapboxAccountManager.start(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

        // This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the account manager
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

                // Customize map with markers, polylines, etc.
            }
        });
    }
    // Add the mapView lifecycle to the activity's lifecycle methods
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you try removing `transitive=true` from the aar dependency, does it change something?

Comment: No, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Not sure if this means anything, but the error message refers to a class that was not added until API 19.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MapBox Android application crashes after update to SDK 4.1.0 when loading credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455165/mapbox-android-application-crashes-after-update-to-sdk-4-1-0-when-loading-creden)

Comment: I was able to get the app to stop crashing by using Mapbox 4.1.1, but still have not found a solution using Mapbox 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've placed all [the permissions](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#permissions) and telemetry service within your manifest. Other then that also make sure you have included the correct imports in your class.

```
E/OfflineManager(3182): Failed to read the storage key: null
```

Gives a clue that you possibly are using offline? Can you post some of your code, your gradle file looks fine.

Comment: I have added my Manifest and Activity files to my post. I am trying to run the app on an Android 4.0.4 with an sdk version 15 if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: You also have this exception: E/MapboxEventManager(3182): Error Trying to load Staging Credentials: java.lang.NullPointerException